# 7 segment display decoder (3 bits of input)

Tags: decoder, bcd

I am trying to wire up a circuit that shows the digits 0 to 7. I have the wiring right because I press each button (shown in picture) and the appropriate numbers light up. I have already made a truth table to point out which decimal goes where so I am good on that part. My only problem is where to wire the rest of the circuit from this point (as seen in the picture). For example, I can't connect two things to S0 therefore I was wondering how to go about solving the issue of connecting the rest of the circuit.

[image: LINK TO PICTURE OF CURCUIT (SIMCIR)[1]]